# Odd geometry nodes (normal) behavior using Align Rotation to Vector node

Tags: modeling, normals, geometry-nodes

Using v2.93.1. I am aiming to apply a collection of hull plates to a cylinder using geometry nodes. I am almost there, but something is wrong with 1 of the tiles alignment - which is presumably due to the cylinders face being mis-aligned? The cylinder was created from a primitive and and a few loops inserted. Bug in geonode maybe? Odd that 3 of the rings look ok. Don't think it is my instance collections objects either as some of these objects are repeated and aligned properly.

Thanks for any pointers.[image]

[blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqDnatCI5_DAjOEVGvP-vEK4s20mrw?e=FAv88k)

Comment: Are you sure your panels collection is ok? If yes, please provide blend file

Comment: Think they are ok - blend file attached - thanks.

Comment: works in 3.0 alpha [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU83V.png

Answer (score 1):

Works in 2.93. So my solution proposal: load the newest Blender version 2.93.

Proof:

[image]

Comment: OK I will download the latest 2.93 beta and see how I go - thank you.